# Where to obtain logs after Xorg freezes

Tags: linux, xorg, perl, urxvt

I have this issue where a perl script will sometimes freeze Xorg. It's an extension for urxvt that detects URLs and allows me to "launch" them in the browser. Sometimes, upon launching, Xorg will freeze. I have not seen a pattern as to when it happens and when it doesn't. My main issue is obtaining more information. The computer won't let me do anything in Xorg, nor switch to another virtual terminal. Should I try looking at the Xorg logs?

Answer (score 2):

there are two log files that you can look, the first one is `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` which logs everything. To view errors in this file you can use the following command:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "(EE)"
```

To view per user errors, you can check this file, in your home directory: `~/.xsession-errors`

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

If Xorg locks up and you can't change to a console, then [Magic SysRq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_sysrq) can allow you to bail out.